# Is it haram to kill a spider

Tags: halal-haram

Salam, I have really bad arachnophobia which is fear of spiders so they way I remove them unfortunately is by killing them. Now I’m very conflicted as to whether this is allowed in Islam mainly because of how they played a role in keeping Prophet Muhammed safe and as a kid I was taught to not kill them. Yet I read on another website that it is allowed. I just wanted to get a proper answer to help ease my thoughts. Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 1):

If the spider is innocent (I.e it may not harm you or may not spread germs and diseases etc..), then it maybe haram for you to kill such spiders.

But if the spider can harm (I.e it may harm you or it could spread germs etc..) it may be totally halal to kill it

Comment: Jazakallah khair